# Using val and def in call by name and call by value in Scala

Tags: scala

Is this an example of call by name and call by value.

To better understand val and dev I've written below :

```
object ByNameAndValue extends App {

  def byName = {
    new Random().nextLong()
  }

  val byValue = {
    new Random().nextLong()
  }

  println(byName)
  println(byName)
  println(byValue)
  println(byValue)
}
```

Which prints :

```
-5953589511279806997
3896193522462630234
1463366495006078511
1463366495006078511
```

Is the function `byName` call by name and therefore evaluated each time it is executed, proven because the random string is different each time `byName` is evaluated?

Is the function `byValue` call by value and therefore is just evaluated once, proven because the random string is generated once in `byValue` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Call by name" and "call by value" refer to the handling of the arguments passed to a function, and neither `byName` nor `byValue` are functions that take arguments. `byName` is a function that takes no arguments and `byValue` is a value not a function.

The difference you are seeing is between a value (`val`) that is evaluated once and a function (`def`) that is evaluated each time it is used.